# cant add value or key in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i was trying to create a flutter app that can connect to my IoT project, but when i add this code

```
Future<void> writeData()async {
    dbRef.child("LightState").set({"switch": !value});
    dbRef.child("FanState").set({"switch": !value});
  }
```

it doesn't add anything in my Firebase Realtime Database. i watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Scrgd43AhZc&t=871s&ab_channel=Tathyanka as refrence but this guy can add the value and key automatically after adding the code above. how do i fix it?

here's my full code:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class IOTScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const IOTScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<IOTScreen> createState() => _IOTScreenState();
}

class _IOTScreenState extends State<IOTScreen> {
  @override
  bool value = false;
  bool values = false;
  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  onUpdate() {
    setState(() {
      value = !value;
    });
  }
  onUpdate2() {
    setState(() {
      values = !values;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.clear_all, size: 30),
                Text(
                  "Egg Incubator",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.settings, size: 30)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Temperature",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "20C",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Humidity",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "60%",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 60,
          ),
          FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {
              writeData();
              onUpdate();
            },
            label: value? Text("Lamp ON"):Text("Lamp OFF"),
            elevation: 20,
            backgroundColor: value? Colors.yellow:Colors.white60, icon: value? Icon(Icons.wb_incandescent): Icon(Icons.wb_incandescent_outlined)
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 60,
          ),
          FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {
              onUpdate2();
            },
            label: values? Text("Fan ON"):Text("Fan OFF"),
            elevation: 20,
            backgroundColor: values? Colors.blueAccent:Colors.white60, icon: values? Icon(Icons.wind_power_rounded): Icon(Icons.wind_power_outlined),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  Future<void> writeData()async {
    dbRef.child("LightState").set({"switch": !value});
    dbRef.child("FanState").set({"switch": !value});
  }
}
```

and my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:incubator_flutter_backend/screens/iotscreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
        '/iotscreen':(BuildContext context)=> IOTScreen()
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: IOTScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i manage to fix it somehow by adding

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeFirebase();
  }
```

and creating a new firebase